# How to give Azure AD "app" permissions to specific SharePoint ("modern") Site folder

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have some SharePoint site created via Microsoft Teams. I want a service application to upload/download files to specific folder of that SharePoint site. I had IT team create a generic account in Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) and then I gave access to that generic account to that specific SharePoint folder.

But, it seems that authenticating the generic account via such username & password always needs interactive login ([Connect PnP Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps)) which is not possible in my scenario because my application is background windows service.

There are other methods in that ConnectPnPOnline command related to using Client ID/Secret/Certificate) but that needs to register an App in Azure AD. I followed [document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-daemon-overview) to get access token created using Client ID and Secret but then the access token is still failing to access the SharePoint folder.

In the Azure AD --> App Registration --> API permissions, permissions can be requested for Sites.Read.All, Sites.Write.All for an application but all that requires IT administrator consent. IT team will not give me such permissions nor I want such permissions granted. I have already given access to that generic account and was looking to see if there is a way that app can inherit (or be given access) to that same SharePoint Site folder.

Comment: Unfortunately that level of granularity is not possible with App-based permissions. `Sites.Selected` is the narrowest scope at this time. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/

Comment: Ok, Thanks Trevor. That document was helpful and I can check with IT team.